# floating popup in all the activities Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

My app is built from activities ( I don't have Fragments), I have a video chat functionality in it, I would like to create a floating chat window in case I want to video chat and navigate through the app, is it possible to achieve without changing the entire structure to fragments?
p.s: I heard about the ([picture in picture](https://www.lifewire.com/picture-in-picture-on-android-4159778)), but I need it to support API 16+ (KitKat),

Thanks!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748442/floating-view-on-android-screen may help you

Comment: looks awesome, but it's connected to a specific activity, I would need it to be in all my activities depending on the user's navigation (I have about 30)

Comment: you can run it on a `service` independently