# Can we create an popupwindows outside of the application ? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to know if it's possible to create a popup window with some buttons outside my application. For example, I'm on twitter and my app creates on popup windows above twitter to do a specific action. After clicking on button apps can write a tweet.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links below. Each thread explains it in different aspects.

[Floating view on Android screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748442/floating-view-on-android-screen)

https://www.android-examples.com/floating-widget/

https://www.journaldev.com/14673/android-floating-widget

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-floating-widget-like-facebook-chat-head/